# How to search many fields separately with Searchkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I started to use the [Searchkick gem](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick) (Elasticsearch) on my Rails 5 app.
Currently I have a search field for a company title. I would like to add a separate dropdown to search for the location separately.

Here is an example of how it would look like:

[image: example form]

Here is my current solution, which works for the title search. But I'm having problems with adding the location search.

Controller:

```
...

 def index
  query = params[:q].presence || "*"
  @companies = Company.search(query, fields: [:title], match: :word_start, page: params[:page], per_page: 6)
 end

...

def company_params
  params.require(:company).permit(:title, :location)
end
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag companies_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

I know have to change the controller and the view. This below is a not working example of the view:

```
<%= form_tag companies_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, nil, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= select_tag :location, options_from_location_field_for_select(Location.all ..?) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you just need a `where` clause.

```
query = params[:q].presence || "*"
location = params[:location].presence || "*"

Company.search(
  query, 
  fields: [:title], 
  match: :word_start, 
  where: { location: location }, 
  page: params[:page], 
  per_page: 6
)
```